# SilverStripe get first children in a row

Tags: templates, silverstripe

I have got multiple children which I display in a grid. 4 children fits in a row. Now I want to give every first and last children in a row an extra class to specify more styles. I tried:

```
<% if FirstInRow %>
    <div class="gridContent firstInRow"></div>
<% else %>
    <div class="gridContent"></div>
<% end_if %>
```

That's the function:

```
function FirstInRow(){
    return ($this->Pos(1) % 4 == 1) ? true : false;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the `Modulus` and `MultipleOf` controls available to you in the template.

```
$Modulus(value, offset) // returns an int
$MultipleOf(factor, offset) // returns a boolean.
```

http://doc.silverstripe.org/sapphire/en/reference/advanced-templates#modulus-and-multipleof

Comment: Thanks, just what I was searching for!

Answer (score 0):

Modulus works better when you could starting from 0.  Try this instead:

```
function FirstInRow(){
    return ($this->Pos(0) % 4 == 0);
}
```

Note that I removed the redunandant ternay operator as well; you can leave that in if it makes the code clearer to you.